# How to display only child category post in related posts in custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

I'm trying to display only those posts which are under the same category of the post which I have clicked as related posts. My custom taxonomy are like this :
Fsc year 1 => Biology => Bio chapter 1 . Now the problem is when I click a post from category bio chapter 1 all the posts in biology and bio chapter 1 display on the page that is the code that I found on google:

```
  <?php
    // get the custom post type's taxonomy terms

    $custom_taxterms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'category', array('fields' => 'slugs') );

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'subject',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'posts_per_page' => -1, // you may edit this number
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'post__not_in' => array ( $post->ID ),
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $custom_taxterms
            )
        )
    );
    $related_items = new WP_Query( $args );
    // loop over query
    if ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : ?>

        <li class="widget widget_categories">
        <h3 class="widget-title">Similar Posts</h3>
        <ul>

        <?php while ( $related_items->have_posts() ) : $related_items->the_post(); ?>

            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a></li>
             <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_content(); ?></a></li>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

        </ul>
        </li>

    <?php endif;
    // Reset Post Data
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
```

I want to display only bio chapter 1 posts as related post not the parent taxonomy's post in these related posts or if I click post from biology taxonomy only posts from biology show not posts from bio chapter 1 category. Can you please help me how I can do this I'm new to WordPress theme development I'll be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps.

--- Get the list of the parent term by using the below function
    `get_term_parents_list`
for documentation of the function => https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_parents_list/

--- Get the ids of the posts that belongs to the parent taxonomy.
--- Use        `post__not_in()`    function in the query to remove the posts belongs to parent taxonomy.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I have fixed the problem by changing terms value.